# Зачем к тегу html добавляют большое количество классов?

Tags: html

Сталкивался с тем, что у тэга `html` в атрибуте `class` перечислено множество значений.
Для чего это применяется?

Вот пример:

```
<html lang="ru" class="js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch 
geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop 
websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius 
boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients 
cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface 
generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers 
applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths no-ipad no-iphone no-ipod no-
appleios positionfixed">
```

Comment: потому что `C` из CSS - это Cascading, а значит указанные свойства могут применяться для вложенных элементов

Comment: @Mr. Music  Что означает "атрибут class со свойствами"? Можете показать пример?

Comment: А почему вопрос заминусован? Объясните, знатоки.

Comment: Какой-нибудь вразумительный ответ будет?

Comment: @Mr. Music  И где здесь свойства?

Comment: @mJeevas Даже если вы хотите ускорить получение ответа, не стоит публиковать свой ответ об этом. В таком случае вы можете оставить комментарий. Публикация ответа – только если вы хотите действительно ответить на вопрос. Это вроде бы очевидно, разве нет?

Comment: @mJeevas Видимо потому, что вопрос был без каких-либо объяснений о чем речь и все подумали об одном - что спрашивается что такое класс и нафиг он нужен. думаю как-то так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это используется для того, чтобы иметь возможность пользоваться каскадными стилями CSS для поддержки определнных фич. Присмотритесь к названиям классов и они многое вам скажут. Например class flexbox подсказывает, что данная страница поддерживает flexbox свойства и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Это похоже на список особенностей клиента, определяемых скриптом [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) (см.  http://habrahabr.ru/post/144352/). Скрипт при подключении определяет свойства браузера и изменяет соответствующие классы тега `html`. В css используя эти классы можно определить различные стили в зависимости от возможностей браузера.